# Cannot build/run Scala project in IntelliJ after packaging with Maven

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea

So my Scala project was working perfectly fine in IntelliJ, then I tried to run package in Maven to obtain a .jar file, which was not working because I was missing a dependency. So I tried to edit pom.xml however reverted it back shortly.

Anyhow, thereafter, without any changes I tried to run my Scala project normally locally and it doesn't work anymore. I get the error:

> Error: Can not find or load main class Name.Name

I double checked Edit Configurations in IntelliJ and the main class is specified.

What went wrong? There has been no changes at all except that I tried to package my project using Maven, and then my normal program stopped working.

Comment: I don't use Maven, but for sbt builds you would typically refresh the build if you make changes to .sbt and IntelliJ gets confused. Perhaps Maven projects also have an option to refresh the model from IntelliJ's perspective? Bottom-left of screen -> "Maven projects" -> Icon that looks like "recycle"

Comment: Maven does have a "recycle" button which reimports all Maven projects. How can I tell if my local run is with Maven or SBT? Because I have both in my project (althought I don't think SBT has been configured), I have been using Maven to build a .jar of my project for production code while locally I am not even sure what was being used. I just ran the program.

Comment: Revert to a clean source tree, and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by recreating the project from scratch, however I'm still unsure what the cause was.